# What to include in an upgrade MSI

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I get how to set up a wix installation to do its upgrade:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/02/15/from-msi-to-wix-part-8-major-upgrade.aspx
What do I include in the upgrade installer though, just the things that changed, or, do I include everything?  Including everything would imply that MSI figures out what changed and only installs the differences.

Scott

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include all the resources in the new package, not just the new ones. As the mentioned article says, the major upgrade will delete all the resources installed by the first version and install the ones from the new one.